# Uppy - is sequential uploads possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, uppy

I am currently developing a service where many of the users have bad internet connection, we are using [Uppy](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/) with the [AWS-s3-multipart](https://uppy.io/docs/aws-s3-multipart/) plugin for uploading files and I really like it so far. One issue we are facing though is that it would be beneficial if they were uploaded sequentially rather than all at once, I.e. that the next upload waits for the first one to finish before it starts. Why? Because if the users loose internet completely they want at least to have some finished content rather than a lot of half-finished content

Now I could off course create a queue myself, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this within Uppy? Would be really nice if I didn't have to work around it outside of Uppy

The service is a webpage that uses Next.js and react for the frontend.